# Test fails when it shouldn't be failing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

I am having this testcase:

```
void loadFromJson() throws Exception
{
    assertThrows(FileNotFoundException.class, ()-> JsonReader.loadFromJson(".json"));
}
```

This should be throwing a FileNotFoundException ... and it does...

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .json (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at org.avalin.optaplanner.json.JsonReader.loadFromJson(JsonReader.java:29)
```

Yet I get this error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.io.FileNotFoundException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.

at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:65)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:38)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:1108)
at org.avalin.optaplanner.test.unitTest.JsonReaderTest.loadFromJson(JsonReaderTest.java:16)
```

And my testcase failed... How is this possible, when it actually throws the requested exception?

Comment: Is `JsonReader` catching the exception? And maybe throwing a different one out?

Comment: What makes you think it throws the exception? I mean... if it actually throws the exception then there are only two possible outcomes: 1) somebody catches it before it gets to your test method, or 2) it propagates back up to your test method. So which case is it for you?

Comment: You're both right, it was a silly mistake of catching the exception inside the JsonReader - I'm a bit confused as I had assumed the first part meant it was actually thrown. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `jupiter.api.AssertThrows`, but it's easy to set up a test which ignores / bypasses that, and simply tests the lambda aspect of your code.

The main point here is that creating a lambda doesn't run the code, until you, er, run the code.

So for example, here are 3 unit tests. `test1` and `test3` both throw the `AssertionError`, but `test2` does not. How that works inside `AssertThrows()`, I will let you or somebody else answer.

```
public class TestTest {

   @Test(expected = AssertionError.class)
   public void test1() {
       throw new AssertionError();
   }

   @Test(expected = AssertionError.class)
   public void test2() {
     Runnable r = () -> {throw new AssertionError();};
   }

   @Test(expected = AssertionError.class)
   public void test3() {
     Runnable r = () -> {throw new AssertionError();};
     r.run();
   }
}
```